# Creating a variable in nested mongodb document

Tags: mongodb

```
_id : { name : xyz,
      Rollnumber : 123}
Stats : [ { subject : Maths,
        Examdate : 2020-08-24 },
        { Subject : English,
        Examdate : 2020-08-24} ]
```

I've a mongodb document like this :
To extract the name and roll number in a variable I can do like:

```
Var a = _id.name;
Var b = _id.rollnumber;
```

I want to extract the Examdate field in a variable , they can be multiples within one document.

`Var c = Stats.Examdate;`
It's returning unknown type error,
I've to use these three variables in a cursor, is there any way to achieve it .

Comment: `var c = Stats.map(stat => stat.Examdate);` this will return an array of all Examdate values from Stats array

Comment: Hi Nicolae , thanks it worked .